# Bootstrap js not being enqueued wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Why is my bootstrap.min.js not being enqueued but my bootstrap.min.css is? here's my code:

```
<?php
    // include custom jQuery
    function shapeSpace_include_custom_jquery() {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js', array(), null, true);
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'shapeSpace_include_custom_jquery');

    function bootstrap(){
        wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.7', true);
        wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css', '3.3.7', true);
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bootstrap');

    function theme_name_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'default_stylesheet', get_stylesheet_uri()); 
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts');
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below code.

```
<?php
// include custom jQuery
function shapeSpace_include_custom_jquery() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js', array(), null, true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'shapeSpace_include_custom_jquery');

function bootstrap(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css', '3.3.7', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bootstrap');

function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'default_stylesheet', get_stylesheet_uri()); 
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts');?>
```

Comment: I tried that and it said Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery at bootstrap.min.js:6 so I added the dependency for jQuery back but removed the true. And now it works so I guess you kinda solved it thanks